# Windows11におけるSSDのパーティションについての質問です

Tags: windows

以前、どこかで「OSがインストールされたドライブとストレージドライブは分けた方がいい。なぜならOSのファイルを参照するときにストレージ分まで見に行って遅くなる場合があるから」という記述を見た記憶があります。

上記を踏まえて、「それであれば、いっそアプリケーションごとにパーティションを区切るともっと早くなる(効率的に参照できる)のでは？」と思いました。

つまり、例えばOS、ゲームA(10GB)、ゲームB(30GB)、ゲームC(50GB)の4つがあるとして、
OS用: 100GB
ゲームA用: 15GBぐらい
ゲームB用: 35GBぐらい
ゲームC用: 60GBぐらい
というパーティションを作ってやれば、それぞれの参照時に参照する範囲が限定されるので非常に効率的なのではないか(読み込みが早いのではないか)と考えました。
※ゲームのアップデートは考えないものとしています

この考え方は、理屈上あっているでしょうか？
現実的かどうかはさておき、いったん自分の考え方が正しいのかを確認したいです。

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: SSDなら無意味では…

Answer (score 1):

質問文中「範囲が限定される」と何か高速化する効果があるとしたら、それはハードディスクメディアのヘッドの移動範囲が限定される、すなわちシーク時間の最小化くらいしか思いつかないです。 SSD で採用されているであろう NAND フラッシュメモリではシーク時間はないので無駄な努力と思われます。
# ウエアレベリングで物理メモリセルが再マップされるとかその辺は略

ハードディスクや SSD を２台以上積むと、その複数台装置に対して並列（同時）に読み書きができる＝高速化が見込めるのですが、１台しかないときパーティション分けても無駄そうです。
# 要するに RAID0 なんだけど、故障耐性が０なのでオイラは使わない。

Answer (score 1):

「以前どこかで見た気がする」で終わらせず、実際にいま調べてみましょう。

---

「SSD パーティション分割 メリット」辺りで google 検索すると、以下のような解説ページや、あなたの質問と同じような Q&A のやり取りがヒットします。

[HDD と SSD、パーティション分割のメリットの違い](https://direct.pc-physics.com/partition/hdd-ssd-partition-division-difference.html)

HDD であれば保存するデータに応じてパーティションを分割することで、断片化を防いで結果的に速度低下も発生しづらくなる…ということはありますが、SSD においては当てはまりません。
(そもそも、HDD/SSD 問わず「参照時に参照する範囲が限定されると効率的」という理屈がよく分からない)

「ゲームのアップデートは考えない」とありますが、セーブデータ等で使用量が増えるケースも考えられます。パーティションを分割することで、むしろ容量が足りなくなった時に融通が利かせづらい問題が出てくることも考慮する必要があると思います。